# How to change position of some element asynchronous use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asynchronous

I have 6 elements and i want to change that element position asynchronous in one function. I want animate this elements when i scroll to top. Now i use pagepilling.js plugin from scrolling. I want create this effect https://youtu.be/G5kBcCCSUzA when scrolling top.

```
<div class="domino-effect">
        <div class="domino-animate-1 domino-animate" 
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
        <div class="domino-animate-2 domino-animate" 
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
        <div class="domino-animate-3 domino-animate" 
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
        <div class="domino-animate-4 domino-animate" 
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
        <div class="domino-animate-5 domino-animate" 
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
        <div class="domino-animate-6 domino-animate"                    
             style="background-image:url(images/home_slide_1.png)">

        </div>
    </div>
```

In first second i want change first element position
In second sec. change second element and so on.

Example of my js code

```
var myyyyFnc = function(elem, fr=1){
    elem.css('top','-80px');
}
for(var fr = 1; fr<=6; fr++){
    setTimeout(myyyyFnc,1000,$(".domino-animate-"+fr));
}
```

I use callbacks from asynch change  ?

Comment: It would be better if you try to animate via `css` than using `javascript` since the animation looks simple. example css domino effect - https://codepen.io/andyfitz/pen/DIglq

Comment: It's good idea. My problem this in this. :) 

I want create this effect :) 

https://youtu.be/G5kBcCCSUzA

When user scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS animation to achieve this.

```css
.domino-effect {
  display: flex;
}

.domino-animate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.domino-animate-1 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 1s ease infinite alternate;
}

.domino-animate-2 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 1.2s ease infinite alternate;
}

.domino-animate-3 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 1.4s ease infinite alternate;
}

.domino-animate-4 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 1.6s ease infinite alternate;
}

.domino-animate-5 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 1.8s ease infinite alternate;
}

.domino-animate-6 {
  animation: animateTop 1s 2s ease infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animateTop {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="domino-effect">
  <div class="domino-animate-1 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
  <div class="domino-animate-2 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
  <div class="domino-animate-3 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
  <div class="domino-animate-4 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
  <div class="domino-animate-5 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
  <div class="domino-animate-6 domino-animate" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/100x200)">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want create this effect :) youtu.be/G5kBcCCSUzA When user scroll up.

Comment: Now, from scroll i use (https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/ ) pagepiling.js plugin.